# React Native FlatList optimization

Tags: react-native

I am seeing very sluggish performance with my following implementation.
Mainly, but not only, when I disable `MealCarousel`, it gets better, since the Carousel renders images.
Another way I can improve performance is by adding `initialNumToRender` to the Main Screen FlatList, but I would really love to see if my components themselves could be improved. I do believe I am not writing an optimized code, but not sure how to improve this. Would really appreciate suggestions and explanations!

### Main Screen

```
const renderResults = useCallback(
  ({ item }) => <RestaurantListRow {...item} />,
  []
);
<FlatList
  ref={topListRef}
  data={results}
  keyExtractor={(item: { id: string }) => `row-${item.id}`}
  renderItem={renderResults}
/>
```

### RestaurantListRow

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Pressable, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { NativeViewGestureHandler } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import MealCarousel, { Pagination } from 'react-native-snap-carousel';
import { View, Divider, Layout, Colors } from 'theme';
import { Restaurant, Meal } from 'types';
import { getCurrentFormattedTime, navigate } from 'utils';

import RestaurantMeal from './RestaurantMeal';

const width = Layout.window.width;
const RestaurantListRow = React.memo(
  ({
    id,
    name,
    rating,
    number_of_ratings,
    meals,
    address,
    phone_number,
    coordinates,
    open_now,
    closes_at,
    pickup_hours_today,
    curbside_pickup,
    opening_hours,
    opening_hours_array,
    categories,
  }) => {
    let favorite_restaurant_open_now = false;
    if (open_now === undefined) {
      const today_from_js = new Date().getDay();
      const today = today_from_js - 1 === -1 ? 6 : today_from_js - 1; 
      const time_now_rounded_down = getCurrentFormattedTime();

      favorite_restaurant_open_now = opening_hours_array
        ? opening_hours_array[today].includes(time_now_rounded_down)
        : false;
    }

    const calculated_open_now = open_now !== undefined ? open_now : favorite_restaurant_open_now;

    const renderItem = React.useCallback(
      ({ index, item }: { index: number; item: Meal }) => {
        return (
          <Pressable
            onPress={() => {
              navigate('Restaurant', {
                index, // Index for pagination
                id,
                name,
                rating,
                number_of_ratings,
                meals,
                coordinates,
                address,
                open_now: calculated_open_now,
                closes_at,
                pickup_hours_today,
                curbside_pickup,
                opening_hours,
                categories,
              });
            }}
            >
            <RestaurantMeal meal={item} />
          </Pressable>
        );
      },
      [
        address,
        categories,
        coordinates,
        curbside_pickup,
        id,
        meals,
        name,
        calculated_open_now,
        closes_at,
        opening_hours,
        pickup_hours_today,
        rating,
        number_of_ratings,
      ]
    );

    const [activeSlide, setActiveSlide] = useState<number>(0);

    return (
      <View>
        <NativeViewGestureHandler disallowInterruption>
          <MealCarousel
            data={meals}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            sliderWidth={width}
            itemWidth={width - 30}
            layout="stack"
            layoutCardOffset={18}
            onSnapToItem={(index) => setActiveSlide(index)}
            vertical={false}
          />
        </NativeViewGestureHandler>
        <Pagination
          dotsLength={meals.length}
          activeDotIndex={activeSlide}
          containerStyle={{ paddingTop: 15, paddingBottom: 0 }}
          dotStyle={{
            width: 8,
            height: 8,
            borderRadius: 5,
            marginHorizontal: 8,
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey_400,
          }}
          inactiveDotOpacity={0.4}
          inactiveDotScale={0.6}
        />
        <Divider />
      </View>
    );
  }
  // () => true
);

export default RestaurantListRow;
```

### Meal

```
import { Skeleton } from '@motify/skeleton';
import { cancelPendingOrder, useMutation } from 'dineden-graphql';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
import { useColorScheme } from 'hooks';
import moment from 'moment';
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { Image, ImageStyle, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import { Colors, Sizes, View, Text, Button, ColorScheme } from 'theme';
import { Meal, Restaurant } from 'types';
import { useStore, PriceBadge, navigate } from 'utils';

const RestaurantMeal = ({
  meal,
  restaurant,
  additionalMealsAvailable,
  showGetThisButton,
  showUpcomingOrderExtras,
  pickup_time,
  showDescription,
  skeletonRadius = 'square',
}) => {
  const { id, image_url, original_price, price_category, title, description } = meal;
  const user = useStore(useCallback((state) => state.user, []));
  const setUpcomingMealCanceled = useStore((state) => state.setUpcomingMealCanceled);

  const upcomingMeal = useStore((state) => state.upcomingMeal);
  const setAlert = useStore(useCallback((state) => state.setAlert, []));

  const [buttonLoading, setButtonLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [imageLoaded, setImageLoaded] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [GQL_cancelPendingOrder, { loading, error, data }] = useMutation(cancelPendingOrder);

  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Skeleton show={!imageLoaded} radius={skeletonRadius}>
          <View style={{ height: '100%' }}>
            <Image
              source={{ uri: image_url }}
              onLoadEnd={() => {
                setImageLoaded(true);
              }}
              resizeMode="cover"
            />
          </View>
        </Skeleton>
        <LinearGradient colors={['transparent', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)']}>
          <View>
            <PriceBadge />
          </View>
          <View>
            <Text>{title}</Text>
            {additionalMealsAvailable && (
              <View>
                <Text>
                  {additionalMealsAvailable} more {additionalMealsAvailable > 1 ? 'meals' : 'meal'}
                </Text>
              </View>
            )}
            {showGetThisButton && (
              <View>
                {upcomingMeal &&
                upcomingMeal.meal.id === id &&
                upcomingMeal.restaurant?.id === restaurant?.id &&
                user ? (
                  <Button
                    title="Selected"
                    size="l"
                    icon={{
                      name: 'check-circle',
                      size: 15,
                      color: 'white',
                      containerStyle: {
                        marginRight: 5,
                      },
                    }}
                    onPress={() => {
                      navigate('Meals', {
                        screen: 'Meals',
                        params: { screen: 'Upcoming' },
                      });
                    }}
                  />
                ) : (
                  <Button
                    title="Get this meal"
                    size="l"
                    onPress={() => {
                      if (user) {
                        if (upcomingMeal) {
                          if (upcomingMeal.pickup_time) {
                            const time_now = moment();
                            const pickup_time = moment(upcomingMeal.pickup_time);
                            if (time_now > pickup_time) {
                              setAlert({
                                type: 'pickupExpired',
                                meal,
                                restaurant,
                              });
                            } else {
                              setAlert({
                                type: 'pickupAlreadyExists',
                                meal,
                                restaurant,
                              });
                            }
                          } else {
                            setAlert({
                              type: 'replaceUpcomingMeal',
                              height: 180,
                              meal,
                              restaurant,
                            });
                          }
                        } else {
                          setAlert({
                            type: 'getThisMeal',
                            height: 180,
                            meal,
                            restaurant,
                          });
                        }
                      } else {
                        setAlert({ type: 'pleaseSignIn' });
                      }
                    }}
                  />
                )}
              </View>
            )}
          </View>
        </LinearGradient>
      </View>
      <Text>{description}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default RestaurantMeal;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const items=[{
   id:1,
   title:'one' 

},{
     id:2,
     title:'two'
}]
//...
renderItem = ({ item }) => (<View key={item.key}><Text>{item.title}</Text></View>);

render(){
  // ...

  <FlatList
    key={(id)=>item.id}
    data={items}
    renderItem={renderItem}
  />

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks Yash. now, I got to know where I did mistake.